# Como implementar a função seno usando série de Taylor em Python?

Tags: python, algoritmo, loop, matemática

Estou com uma dificuldade no meu código. Eu preciso criar um código que calcula o seno de um ângulo utilizando a série de Taylor, no intervalo de [-pi, +pi]. Assim, a função seno se repete. Ou seja, o valor do seno do angulo de pi/6 é igual ao valor do angulo de 5pi/6. Então se você passar um angulo fora do intervalo [-pi,pi], o programa deve encontrar o equivalente dele intervalo. O ângulo passado como parâmetro para a função deve estar em radianos. Sendo a entrada, o ângulo em radianos (x) e o incremento (n).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O meu código está assim,

```
import math
 
def seno(x, grau):
    
    assert type(grau) == int, "Seno: O grau do polinômio não é um inteiro"
    assert grau >= 0, "Seno: O grau do polinômio não é positivo"
    assert (grau % 2) == 1, "Seno: O grau do polinômio não é impar"
    
    
    if (-math.pi >= x >= math.pi):    
        senx = 0        
        for n in range (0, grau, 1):               
            senx = senx + (-1)**n*((x**(2*n+1))/(math.factorial(2*n+1)))
                
    else:    
        senx = 0        
        y = (math.pi + x) % (2*math.pi)     
        z = y - math.pi    

        for n in range (0, grau, 1):    
            senx = senx + (-1)**n*((z**(2*n+1))/(math.factorial(2*n+1)))    
    
    return (senx)
```

Eu consegui encontrar o cálculo que "converte" ângulos maiores que o intervalo [-pi,pi] para dentro do intervalo. Mas o meu problema é, para ângulos que já estão no intervalo eu não preciso fazer esse cálculo. Então estou tentando criar uma condição, utilizando o if para ângulos (x) no intervalo.

Comment: O que seria "implementar o ângulo"? Você precisa garantir que o ângulo passado está no intervalo [-π, π]? Você precisa converter o ângulo passado para o intervalo [-π, π]? O ângulo passado como parâmetro para a função deve estar em graus ou radianos? Você pode fornecer um exemplo de chamada de função que não executa como você esperava?

Comment: Assim, a função seno se repete. Ou seja, o valor do seno do angulo de pi/6 é igual ao valor do angulo de 5pi/6. Então se você passar um angulo fora do intervalo [-pi,pi], o programa deve encontrar o equivalente dele dentro do intervalo. O ângulo passado como parâmetro para a função deve estar em radianos. Mas se você me ajudar a descobrir pq o código não está funcionando, já estou muito grato.

Comment: @GuilhermeMello, não sei se você sabe mas a declaração [`assert`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=assert#the-assert-statement) apenas é verificada em modo de [depuração](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#__debug__). Não use `assert` para emitir mensagens de erro, é só uma ferramenta de testes.

Comment: @AugustoVasques foi pedido na atividade que usasse.

Answer (score 0):

A série de Taylor para a função seno é valida [para todo valor de x](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seno#Defini%C3%A7%C3%A3o_anal%C3%ADtica), portanto não é preciso se preocupar o caso de o valor não estar no intervalo [-π, π]. Vamos utilizar seu exemplo de π/6 e 5π/6 comparando com a definição da função seno pela biblioteca `math`:

```py
import math

def seno(x, n):
    senx = 0        
    for i in range(0, n):               
        senx += (-1)**i*((x**(2*i+1))/(math.factorial(2*i+1)))
    return senx

print(seno(math.pi/6, 21))    # Utilizando sua função:   0.49999999999999994
print(math.sin(math.pi/6))    # Utilizando a biblioteca: 0.49999999999999994

print(seno(5*math.pi/6, 21))  # Utilizando sua função:   0.4999999999999997
print(math.sin(5*math.pi/6))  # Utilizando a biblioteca: 0.49999999999999994
```